# JSON decode is not working

Tags: php, json

This is my 3.txt file:
[image: json file]

I don't know why it works when it has only 1 data and when it has more data it's not working.

This is my code:

[image: code]

Comment: `3.txt` doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: The contents from the image above are stored incorrectly. Each object, denoted by the opening and closing brackets `{}`, must be followed by a `,` to denote a separation of objects. As it stands, your JSON is invalid and will not function. Try running the contents of the text file through something like [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  Ok i fixed it  that work   can i ask you any Question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your *3.txt* does not contain a valid json. You need to adjust your sample string to be valid JSON by adding quotes around strings, commas between objects and placing the objects inside a containing array (or object).
It should be something like this,

```
 [{"address":"+6161616","body":"asda","date":"1231"},
{"address":"+616sdfs6","body":"as3sda","date":"155231"},
{"address":"+6161616","body":"asda","date":"123551"}]
```

You can test if a json is valid [here](http://jsonlint.com/).